# Google-Script GetRange Multiplying instead of Adding?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a code which should input a calendar event then insert a note into the cell saying "Inputted". This part works, but only to an extent.

If I have more than one event (on separate lines), it will say "Input" as I want on the first one. But for others, it then creates a note 10 rows down instead of 1. Looking at my code, I can't see anything that would cause it to do this - as the calendar events are created perfectly. I believe it lies in the `var Comment` section - but there's no multiplication there!

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?!

```
  function CalendarInput() {

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

       var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
      var numRows = 3;   // Number of rows to process
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 26); //What data will be used
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar(); //Gets the correct calendar
    for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      var title = row[2];  // Column with Title
      var desc = row[8];       // Column with Description
      var date = row[3];   //Column with Date
      var edate = row[4] //Column with end date
      var loc = row[9];    //Column with Location
      var invite = row[11] //Column with Invite List
      var sent = row[12] //Check Sent
      var check = row[7]
      var Comment = sheet.getRange(i+startRow, 7).setNote("Inputted")


              cal.createAllDayEventSeries(title, new Date(date), CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().until(new Date(edate)), {description:desc,location:loc,guests:invite})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are documented warnings about the use of `for..in` to loop over Arrays, see [this Description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for example.

The problem you're seeing is being caused by the way `for..in` works in apps-script.

#### Demo Code

This test function will demonstrate what's going on when you `.setComment()` on row `i + startRow`:

```
function test() {
  var data = [ [2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2],[6,7,8,9],[9,8,7,6] ];
  var startRow = 2;
  var i;

  Logger.log("for (var i in data)");
  for (i in data) {
    Logger.log( i + startRow );
  }
  Logger.log(typeof i);

  Logger.log("for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++)");
  for (i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
    Logger.log( i + startRow );
  }
  Logger.log(typeof i);
}
```

#### Logging Output

```
[13-06-01 22:41:10:046 EDT] for (var i in data)
[13-06-01 22:41:10:046 EDT] 02
[13-06-01 22:41:10:046 EDT] 12
[13-06-01 22:41:10:046 EDT] 22
[13-06-01 22:41:10:046 EDT] 32
[13-06-01 22:41:10:047 EDT] string

[13-06-01 22:41:10:047 EDT] for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++)
[13-06-01 22:41:10:047 EDT] 2.0
[13-06-01 22:41:10:047 EDT] 3.0
[13-06-01 22:41:10:047 EDT] 4.0
[13-06-01 22:41:10:047 EDT] 5.0
[13-06-01 22:41:10:047 EDT] number
```

#### What's happening?!

When the `for..in` loop is used, the looping variable `i` is a string - The looping variable `i` is of type String - and so you get string behavior for operators like `+`. When `i + startRow` is executed, `startRow` is coerced to a string, then is concatenated to `i`, which was already a string.

On the other hand, in the `for` loop, the same statement results in a mathematical operation, since both operands are of type number.

#### Don't use for..in for Array operations

It's short, it often works, but break the habit.

Use this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
  ...
```